# Application Request Routing redirected calls fail when machine names are used

Tags: iis, authentication, request

I am having two servers in my application. One is web server and another is app server. I have a static file in my application server inside my IIS Web Application. App Server web application is enabled with Windows Authentication. I have created URL rewrite using ARR for calls with specific URL to get redirected to the static file.

When I use IP address in my URL and call web server from client machine, things works fine. When I use machine name, I am getting 401 error.

1) I checked on the IIS Logs -> When call fails, repeated attempt was made by client to connect with web server and all calls failed with 401 error. From web server to app server, call was made only one and it returned 401 error.
2) When call success scenario, two 401 failure in web server and one 401 failure in app server. after that one success call in both web server and app server.

I also checked on Failure Request Tracing and didn't get additional information.

Below is the configuration I have in web server for ARR.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Test Model" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Sample/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://appserver/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Let me know if more information is required.

Regards,
Madhan

Answer (score 2):

The above issue was due to a Kerberos issue. We registered the SPN for the runtime account of the accessed URL (basically the Application Pool account in which Virtual Application is running) in the application server against the web server. After this, calls were accepted in the application server and required response was returned back.